# What is wrong with my simple linear regression?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, linear-regression

I fail to find the theta using this code.

I added plotting code to help visualize the issue.

Please, help me find the bug in this short block of code

Thanks

[image: Normal Equation used in linear function]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 20

def arr(n):
    return np.arange(n) + 1

def linear(features, y):
    x = np.vstack(features).T
    xT = np.transpose(x)
    xTx = xT.dot(x)
    return np.linalg.inv(xTx).dot(xT).dot(y)

def plot(x, y, dots_y):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.plot(x, dots_y, marker='o', linestyle=' ', color='r')
    plt.show()    

y = arr(N) ** 2 + 3    
theta = linear((np.ones(N), arr(N), arr(N) ** 2), y)

plot(arr(N), arr(N) ** theta[1] + theta[0], y)
```

[image: Output plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the plotting line, which should be

```
plot(arr(N), arr(N)**2 * theta[2] + arr(N) * theta[1] + theta[0], y)
```

according to the quadratic polynomial model.

Also; I suppose  you did the computation of least-square solution this way for expository reasons, but in practice, linear least squares fit would be  obtained with `np.linalg.lstsq` as follows, with much shorter and more efficient code:

```
N = 20
x = np.arange(1, N+1)
y = x**2 + 3
basis = np.vstack((x**0, x**1, x**2)).T  # basis for the space of quadratic polynomials 
theta = np.linalg.lstsq(basis, y)[0]   # least squares approximation to y in this basis
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')                   # original points
plt.plot(x, basis.dot(theta))          # best fit
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]